# What's wrong with this XML file?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Audio sfxVol="255" musicVol="255" />
<Video resolution="1280x960" screenMode="Windowed" antiAlias="0" />
<Input devType="keyboard">
    <KeyBinding ID="up" keyCode="82" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="down" keyCode="81" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="left" keyCode="80" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="right" keyCode="79" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="enter" keyCode="88" keyMod="0" />
</Input>
```

I always getting a "Junk found after document element" error when I try to parse it.

Comment: Mark any answer as a correct if you've solved it :)

Answer (score 4):

XML documents require a single root element. An element that contains all the others.

The first start tag in the document is `<Audio>`. It is a self-closing tag so it closes it self. That is the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it all in a single element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
    [your stuff goes here]
</Data>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I always getting a "Junk found after document element" error when I try to parse it.

Yes, of course because it doesn't have a `root (parent) element`. See the [`xml_tree_structure`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_tree_structure.htm).

> The tree structure contains root (parent) elements, child elements and so on.

So in your code should be an item that act as a `root (parent) element` on this case I would put `Audio` as a `root` **BUT** I don't know if it would mess your expect stuff, so your code should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Audio sfxVol="255" musicVol="255">
<Video resolution="1280x960" screenMode="Windowed" antiAlias="0" />
<Input devType="keyboard">
    <KeyBinding ID="up" keyCode="82" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="down" keyCode="81" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="left" keyCode="80" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="right" keyCode="79" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="enter" keyCode="88" keyMod="0" />
</Input>
</Audio>
```

Comment: I didn't do it, but I would guess because in this case you put video inside of audio, which... who knows... maybe is fine, but probably smelly from a data context

Comment: @GradyPlayer well now I've edited my answer trying to explain it a little bit

Answer (score 0):

XML file **must have a root** element.It is a rule.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<Audio sfxVol="255" musicVol="255" />
<Video resolution="1280x960" screenMode="Windowed" antiAlias="0" />
<Input devType="keyboard">
    <KeyBinding ID="up" keyCode="82" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="down" keyCode="81" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="left" keyCode="80" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="right" keyCode="79" keyMod="0" />
    <KeyBinding ID="enter" keyCode="88" keyMod="0" />
</Input>
</root>
```

[check this link to learn xml rules](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)